# Rails: embedded Ruby in a JS event handler not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently pretty well versed in Ruby and JS, and picking up Rails. I've created a minimal Rails app, and I'm working on calling a Ruby method from a JavaScript event handler (button click event handler). The method should sample a deck of cards and display the result.

I created the app by issuing these commands:

```
rails new blackjack
cd blackjack
bin/rails generate controller Games blackjack
rails s
```

I have touched two files in this: `./app/views/games/blackjack.html.erb` and `./app/controllers/games_controller.rb`. Here's the code in these two files:

**games_controller.rb**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def blackjack
    @game = Game.new
  end
end

class Deck
  CARD_VALUES = {
    '2'  => 2,
    '3'  => 3,
    '4'  => 4,
    '5'  => 5,
    '6'  => 6,
    '7'  => 7,
    '8'  => 8,
    '9'  => 9,
    '10' => 10,
    'J'  => 10,
    'Q'  => 10,
    'K'  => 10,
    'A'  => 11
  }.freeze

  RANKS = %w(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A).freeze

  # UTF codes for suit symbols
  SUITS = ["\u2660", "\u2661", "\u2662", "\u2663"].freeze

  attr_reader :cards

  def initialize
    new_deck
  end

  def new_deck
    @cards = RANKS.product(SUITS).shuffle
  end
end

class Game
  attr_reader :deck

  def initialize
    @deck = Deck.new
  end
end
```

**blackjack.html.erb**

```
<p id="card" style="font-size:48px">Card: <%= @game.deck.cards.sample %></p>

<button id="button-card">Card</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('button-card').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let card = `<%= @game.deck.cards.sample %>`;
  card = card.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
  document.getElementById('card').innerText = 'Card: ' + card;
});
</script>
```

What happens is this. When I open the page, it displays a random card, for example `["6", "♢"]`, when the `#sample` method on the first line gets called. This is as I expected. When I click the `Card` button, I get another random card, also as I expected. But when I click the `Card` button again, or any number of times, the card stays the same. I have determined that the `sample` method in the `click` handler gets called every time I click the `Card` button, but the same card value keeps getting plugged in to the `p` tag. Also, if I reload the page, I get a new card as expected.

So, I'm probably missing something fundamental about how embedded Ruby works with JavaScript on the client side.

I'm sure that this isn't a conventional way to do things in Rails, but I'm trying to get a good understanding of how embedded Ruby works in Rails. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Using embedded Ruby in your JS is just not a good idea. It makes it harder to debug or reason about your JS and placing your JS in inline script tags creates issues when Turbo/Turbolinks replaces the page contents dynamically. You don't actually need it either - if you want to pass data from the server to the JS world use data attributes.

Comment: Those issues are what I guess is happening here - when you navigate around the page that junk script is attaching the event handler over and over and when you click the button they all run in the order they were attached. The last one wins. The solution here is to rethink this idea. Put your JS in a external file and stop attaching everything to element ids. Don't think "I want this button on this page to do X". Think "I want this class of button to behave like X" and you'll be well on your wy to writing better js.

Comment: @max Thanks Max. I agree that this isn't a good idea. I'd say that's intuitively obvious! But I still want to understand better WHY it isn't a good idea. JS won't execute embedded Ruby if it's in another file, by the way. (I tried with application.js first.) Now, I added a duplicate button and click handler, and they both behave in the same way: first click changes the value and subsequent clicks do not. I'll look into data attributes. (more)

Comment: @max What I'm actually looking for is a way to port a Ruby blackjack game I wrote from a terminal-based UI to a browser-based one. I could rewrite it in JS of course, but I'd like to see if I can use Rails to embed code in the manner of PHP. I realize that that isn't a typical use case for Rails, but I'm particularly interested in gaining a deeper understanding of how ERB embeds Ruby code in HTML pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with ERB which is just yet another templating engine.

Rather the issue is that Turbo creates a peristent session across pages (like many modern javascript frameworks) and writing non-idemepotent code like this just isn't going to cut it today. You would have the same issues irregardless of what language you're using on the back end.

What happens with your script tag is that its re-evaluated every time the page is visited by Turbolinks. The event handlers will just stack on top of each other and the last one wins. This creates the typical "But WAH! It works when I reload the page!" scenario.

Instead just create a delegated idempotent event handler in an external script:

```erb
# Interpolate data into your HTML - not your JS.
<%= tag.button "Card",
    class: "button-card",
    data: {
      target: "#card",
      foo: "rab".reverse
    }
%>
```

```js
// please put this JS in your assets pipeline
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (!event.target.matches('button-card')) return;
  let data = event.target.dataset;
  let targetCard = document.querySelector(data.target);
  targetCard.innerText(data.foo);
});
```

This works even across page visits since the event handler is bound to the document and not the individual elements. And as you can see you don't need ERB interpolation in your scripts.

The [Stimulus.js library](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/) which underpins Turbo works on the same basic principles - delegated event handers and data attributes as a means of passing state.

If you really want to continue down the dead end road of interpolating data into your JS with ERB you at least need to make sure to remove any previous event handlers so that the effects of your script doesn't stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've redesigned things to match what you have here, but it still doesn't solve the problem. I can clarify my question by forgetting about cards. Suppose I replace your `foo: "rab".reverse` with `value: (1..10).to_a.sample`. I'd like a different random number each time I click the button. But I don't get that, because `value` is assigned when the button is rendered, and the event handler doesn't allow me to call the `#sample` method to get a new random number. Is there a way to refresh the random number in the event handler context? (more ...)

Comment: More generally, I have to believe that there's a way to trigger Ruby methods from a JS event handler, because that's what happens when a JS event handler accesses data from a Rails application, isn't it? So how do I do that, when all I need is a session to maintain state and don't need to access a DBMS?

Comment: Yes it's called ajax.

Comment: Right, right. Ok, so if I want to get Ruby to serve me up a new random number every time I click a button on a web page, I have to do an HTTP call to a server and return said number? Meaning, perhaps set up a route on the back end and use `fetch` to call it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is no way run to Ruby on the client (barring expeimental stuff like NaCL).

Comment: All right. Thanks, Max! I appreciate your help.